# Remove and redo divs from DOM by resolution with jQuery .detach()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a group of divs at a special resolution (for example 480px) from the DOM. I have two problems with my script:

1. It can remove my divs as I want but not redo them.
2. It seemes like, that it fires all the time - is that the right way?

My script:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var MobileTable = $( ".container" ).length;

    if ($('body').outerWidth() <= 480 ){
        if (MobileTable) {
            $(".container").detach();
        }
    }

    else if ($('body').outerWidth() > 480 ){
        if (!MobileTable) {
            $(".wrapper").append(MobileTable);
        }
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">Hello 1
      <span class="content">Some Content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">Hello 2
      <span class="content">Some Content</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3gajduyh/3/

And a basic question - does the DOM remove execute before the page is completely loaded, or not (if I adding it in the `<head>` section)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assign detach() method to a variable!

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    var MobileTable = $( ".container" ).length;

    if ($('body').outerWidth() <= 480 ){
        if (MobileTable) {
            revoke=$(".container").detach();
        }
    }

    else if ($('body').outerWidth() > 480 ){
        if (!MobileTable) {
            $(".wrapper").append(revoke);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">Hello 1
      <span class="content">Some Content</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">Hello 2
      <span class="content">Some Content</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```